# How is "namespaces" used in chrome.storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I can't seem to find any documentation on the namespace part of chrome.storage. How is it used?

I'm developing an extension which I have split up into "modules", in the sense that the user can enable and disable parts of it and they all have different settings. Would it make sense to put their settings in different namespaces?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Namespace` is the string name of a [StorageArea](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea).

The only case where it's used in API as a separate entity is the `onChanged` event listener where the namespace is passed as a string parameter: `"sync"`, `"local"`, `"managed"`.